# Loop in a dynamic shuffling list

Tags: java, sorting, graph-algorithm

Here is the case: Given two lists [A,B,C,D] and [Ob,Od,Oa,Oc] (Object O has a parameter A,B,C or D)

The first listed was sorted according to a specific condition (if A was a product, it's the cheapest and D the most expensive). We want to do a 2-for loops this way:

```
List products = [A,B,C,D];
List shops = [Ob,Od,Oa,Oc];
int k=0;
for(Object i : products)
    for(Object o : shops)
        // 1st loop i is A, and o is Ob
        consume(A,Ob) // We are reducing number of A depending on Ob requirement
        k++; // 1st loop k = 0;
```

For Ob, we know that a B is better than an A. So, being in the first loop, I would like to switch between A and B, so my list becomes [B,A,C,D].

```
List products = [B,A,C,D]; // during the first loop, this list was shuffled.    
List shops = [Ob,Od,Oa,Oc];
int k=0;
for(Object i : products)
    for(Object o : shops)
        // 2nd loop i is B, and o is Od --> B because we shifted
        consume(A,Ob) // We are reducing number of A depending on Ob requirement
        k++; // 2nd loop k = 1;
```

At the last loop, we should have [B,D,A,C].

Of course, doing this in a parallelised system with one thread per combination of list [A,B,C,D], and then returning the optimal solution is doable, but difficult.

Is there anyway in Java to shuffle the list on which we are iterating?

Comment: I would call [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) *once* before I begin iterating.

Comment: `Collection.shuffle(list)` does a random shuffle. Whereas in my case, the shuffle depends on conditions.